# Python Program to continuously move consonants to end of string until the first letter is vowel

Tags: python, string, loops

So for example, if I input `bob`, it should give me `obb`. Likewise, something like `plank` should give me `ankpl`.

```
s = input("What word do you want translated?")
first = s[0]
vowel = "aeiou"
for i in range (1, len(s)):
     if first in vowel:
        s = s + "way"
        print (s)
else:
        s = s[1:] + s[0]
        print (s)
```

This currently is only giving me `lankp` for `plank`.
Thanks!

Comment: atwhay areway ouyay yingtray ootay ooday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can actually be made much simpler:

```
s = raw_input("What word do you want translated?").strip()
vowel = set("aeiou")
if vowel & set(s):
    while s[0] not in vowel:
        s = s[1:] + s[0]
    print s
else:
    print "Input has no vowels"
```

Comment: I was overthinking it, thank you for the answer! Question: what does .strip() do?

Comment: making vowel a set would be nice, although for this problem it's obviously not necessary (i.e. `vowel = set("aeiou")`)

Comment: @Anonmly first, `raw_input` is what you want, because just plain `input` does eval on user input. The `strip` removes whitespace from the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @JasonSundram Edited just for you.

Comment: What if there are no vowels in there?

Comment: @Gnibbler Haven't though of that yet... hmmm, I guess for this question we assume it has a vowel?

Comment: @korylprince, awww, thanks. I guess you might want to throw in an `assert(vowel & set(s))` to avoid the infinite loop, too.

Comment: @JasonSundram the problem with assert is that it does not always run (for instance if python is called with `-O`.) I added a simple `if` statement instead.

Comment: `if` beats `assert` -- just wanted to make sure there was _something_ there.

Answer (score 1):

You only set `first = s[0]` once and that is done before the loop. You probably want to set it inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your program is that the `else` isn't indented to the correct level,so you have an `for/else` construct instead of an `if/else`.

Here is a more efficient approach.

if `vowels = set("aeiou")`, you can get the position of the first vowel like this

```
next(i for i, j in enumerate(s) if j in vowels)
```

eg:

```
>>> s = "plank"
>>> vowels = set("aeiou")
>>> next(i for i, j in enumerate(s) if j in vowels)
2
```

and

```
>>> s[2:] + s[:2]
'ankpl'
```

So now you only need to manipulate the string once.

If there are no vowels, the code raises an exception instead of running forever :)

```
>>> s="why why why?"
>>> next(i for i, j in enumerate(s) if j in vowels)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a little more efficient to search for the vowel and then do the string rotate once:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

for index, character in enumerate(s):
    if character in vowels: break

s = s[index:] + s[:index]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
#Move Consonants to the End
def MoveConsonants(input1):
    contains_vowel = False
    for letter in input1: #Check if the work contains a vowel or not
        if letter in 'aeiou':
            contains_vowel = True
    #If the word doesn't contain a vowel, return the same word
    if not contains_vowel: 
        return input1

    #Check if the first letter is a vowel, if so, we can return the string
    if input1[0] in 'aeiou':
        return input1

    #if the first letter is not a vowel, move the first letter to the end and repeat the process
    input1 = input1[1:] + input1[0]
    return MoveConsonants(input1)
print(MoveConsonants('Plank'))
```

Comment: It would be helpful for OP if you explain why this will work. "Give a man a fish..."